# cant extend graphql types in subgraph

Tags: typescript, apollo-federation

I am using apollo federation and typescript to create subgraphs and a graphql federated server. I defined a type in one subgraph and I want to extend it and add a field to it in another subgraph. So in typedefs I use the syntax.

```
extend type MyType @key(fields: "id"){
    id: ID! @external
    myAddedField: [String]
}
```

But I get an error.

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "extend"
```

Is there something wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue just by removing a description-comment before it.
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2385